# Swift: Make launch image appear slightly longer?

Tags: ios, swift

So while I realize leaving your launch image up for a long time can seem annoying or pretentious to the user, when I launch the Xcode simulator, the launch image only stays up for 0.5 sec - 1 sec. I want it to stay for like 1 more second.

How can I do this?

Comment: Actually, in your AppDelegate.swift - 
    sleep(2) - For 2 seconds

Answer (score 3):

You could add a `UIImageView` to your view controller's view, then use an `NSTimer` or `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` call to call a method to remove it.

Comment: That's pretty much the only way to do it. :)

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me in Obj-C is just putting this in the app delegate didFinishLaunching

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.5];
```

0.5 being the number of seconds to wait. So I would assume in Swift it would just be

```
NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(0.5);
```

Put that in the App Delegate with your interval.

Comment: Are you sure this will not stop main thread? If there is some stuff being downloaded, will it not be suspended?